# Where to put invalid event listener

Tags: backbone.js

I have a validate function in my model which looks like

```
validate: function(attributes, options) {
    if(attributes.name == "") {
        return 'Please provide a name';
    }
},
```

I then add this model to a collect and create a new collection and add my event listener for when the validation of my model fails

```
var TheCollection = new MyCollection;

TheCollection.on('invalid', function(model, errors) {
    //Do something
});
```

Is this the correct place to put my listener?  I'm pretty sure its not but I don't know where else to put it.  Do I need to put it in a view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would say it belongs in the view. Presumably you have a function of some kind defined in the view to handle saving the model, and bound to an appropriate event, such as clicking the submit button. In that function I would first call `model.isValid()`, and then, based on the response from that, either save the valid model or return an error to the user.

As a general rule of thumb, if you would put something in the controller in a server-side MVC framework, then the view is usually the best place to put it in Backbone. Personally I find that Backbone's general philosophy is similar to the MTV philosophy behind Django, with views taking the place of controllers.